# UWP API Client throws ObjectDisposedException in response.Content and returns partial data

Tags: post, uwp, asp.net-core-webapi, httpclient

I have a UWP client which sends a POST request to a ASP Core Server to request data from a database.
The request returns a success code 200, but the deserialized data is incomplete, and by checking with debugger at response.Content it says:
`Length = '((System.IO.BufferedStream)(System.Net.Http.StreamContent)response.Content)._content).Length' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'`.
Same goes for Position, ReadTimeout and WriteTimeout.

My code is:

```
using (HttpClient Http = new HttpClient())
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync<ChartDataRequest>(string.Concat("http://localhost:5242/", "MyDbController"), chartDataRequest))
            {
                HttpContent content = response.Content;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var chartDataResponse = content.ReadAsAsync<ChartDataResponse>();
                    DataText.Text = chartDataResponse?.Result.ResponseMessage;
                    List<Bic_OHLC> moreCandles = chartDataResponse?.Result.ChartData.OHLCs;

                    SyncMoreCandles(moreCandles);
                }
                else DataText.Text = response.ReasonPhrase;
            }
```

The `List<Bic_OHLC>` should have about 180 elements, but here are returned only 100 elements.
To note that if I make the same POST request using a Blazor wasm client, it returns the entire list.

I assume is because the response is quite big on data and the response object is disposed before it's fully read, but I can't get it to work. Note, _bufferSize is set to 0, if that matters.